# Import leaftlet-control-geocoder in Angular 8 Project?

Tags: javascript, angular, dictionary, leaflet, geocoder

angular verison: 8

version in package.json:

```
"leaflet": "1.5.1",
"leaflet-draw": "1.0.4",
"leaflet-sidebar-v2": "3.0.3",
"esri-leaflet": "2.3.2",
"leaflet-control-geocoder": "1.10.0"
```

I have import leaflet and other like this:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-draw';
import * as esri from 'esri-leaflet';
import 'leaflet-sidebar-v2';
import 'leaflet-control-geocoder';
```

Now i have to use or leaflet-control-geocoder to implement this function but if i write this:

```
L.control.geocoder().addTo(map);
```

angular crash.(Property 'geocoder' does not exist on type 'typeof Control')
I try also with esri-leaflet-geocoder, but it's crash too.

any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by doing so

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import Geocoder from 'leaflet-control-geocoder';
...
this.map = L.map('map', {
    center: [staticLatLng.lat, staticLatLng.lng], 
    zoom: zoomLevel
});
const GeocoderControl = new Geocoder();
GeocoderControl.addTo(this.map);
GeocoderControl.on('markgeocode', function (e) {
console.log(e);
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try with uppercase "C" `L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map)`

or (but that should have the same effect)

```
var geocoder = new L.Control.geocoder();
map.addControl(geocoder);
```

Comment: Same result. Property 'geocoder' does not exist on type 'typeof Control'

Comment: Then look into : https://github.com/consbio/Leaflet.ZoomBox/issues/15#issuecomment-429856018 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42620830/property-draw-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-control

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I added the geocoder inside L.Routing.control, and it works! (actually, VS Code still says `Property 'Geocoder' does not exist on type 'typeof Control'`) but it works!:

`L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [L.latLng(57.74, 11.94), L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)],
      showAlternatives: true,
      geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim()
    }).addTo(this.map);`

I'm working with Angular 8, leaftlet-routing-machine plugin.

Comment: I find a solution!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-geosearch

https://smeijer.github.io/leaflet-geosearch/#search

Here there are all that i need!